# Cannot downcast from ... to a more optional type

Tags: ios, swift

First of all I've got "ApiModel" protocol, which is simply empty. Then I've got model struct "Pokemon", which implements ApiModel protocol. Now I'm trying to convert array of ApiModel ( [ApiModel] ) to array of Pokemon   [Pokemon], so I'm using this function:

```
if let pokemonsList = objects as! [Pokemon]? {
                        self.pokemons = pokemonsList
                    }
```

objects - is non optional let variable, which holds [ApiModel].

But I've got following error:
Cannot downcast from '[ApiModel]' to a more optional type '[Pokemon]?'

When I'm trying to do that on single model it's working fine:

```
if let poke = objects.first as! Pokemon? {
                        self.pokemon = poke
                    }
```

Also, if objects will be optional - again it's working fine.

Can you help me to understand why arrays doesn't works?

Comment: Instead of `x as! T?` you should do `x as? T`, otherwise you will just have a crash.

Comment: Imagine what you are going to do: *You forced downcast an optional to an optional*. Sounds pretty weird, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had mistake in `if let` syntax. Instead of force cast you want to have optional cast. And since you already have this array you don't want get optional array of pokemons

```swift
if let pokemonsList = objects as? [Pokemon] {
    self.pokemons = pokemonsList
}
```